# How to resume Scrapy spider where it left off?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a very large website with lots of URLs I would like to spider. Is there a way to tell Scrapy to ignore a list of URLs?

Right now I store all the URLs in a DB column, I would like to be able to restart the spider but pass the long list (24k rows) to Scrapy so it knows to skip the ones it has already seen.

Is there anyway to do this?

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.5,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 0,
        'JOBDIR': 'jobs/scrapy_1'
    }

    name = None
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            yield response.follow(link.url, self.parse)
```

Comment: If you provide some code, it would be helpful. Otherwise answers could not fit to your needs.

Comment: I added my code. I see scrapy offers jobs, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/jobs.html. However, with this current setup, it doesn't seem like scrapy is correctly picking up where the last job left off.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store the scraped URLs somewhere, I usually do it in MySQL, then when I restart scraper, I ignore them like this

```
class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM table")

        already_scraped = tuple(a['url'] for a in cursor.fetchall())

        for link in le.extract_links(response):
            if url not in already_scraped:
                yield Request(...)
            else:
                self.logger.error("%s is already scraped"%(link.url))
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer, also notice I used `tuple` instead of `list` ... its because tuple use less memory than `list`

Comment: Could you clarify what newUrls is supposed to be?

Comment: :P I wrote `newUrls` just for your understanding, `newUrls` is the list of new urls you want to scrape

Comment: But it's a spider. I don't have an exact list of newURLs

Comment: as suggested, save all scraped urls into database, and then do what I said, ignore them at all, dont scrape if they exist in database

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't follow the code you provided. How do I do this? The line:

for url in newUrls doesn't make sense. I don't have a list of newUrls. How do I ignore already scraped ones?

Answer (score 0):

Check the information in your database:

```
def check_duplicate_post_links(self, links):
    new_links = []
    for link in links:
        sql = 'SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE url = %s'
        self.cursor.execute(sql, (url,))
        duplicate_db = self.cursor.fetchall()

        if duplicate_db:
            self.logger.error("error url duplicated: {}".format(link))
        else:
            new_links.append(link)

    return new_links


class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        links = le.extract_links(response):
        new_links = self.check_duplicate_post_links(links)

        if len(new_links) > 0:
            for link in new_links:
                #Add your information
                item = YourScrapyItem()
                item['url'] = link.url

                yield item
```